# Primefaces Datatable search for filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

The default setting updates the table on each keystroke in the filter field.I want to display the result list only when the user enters something and presses enter.

Comment: Can you post your code (xhtml?) of how you implemented this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated your version, but you can use the `enter` event on `filterEvent` since PF 3.2. Earlier version , you can use [this javascript workaround](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-filter-pdatatable-on-enter-event.html)

Answer (score 2):

for global filter you can use `event.keyCode == 13`

like this

```
<f:facet name="header">  
    <p:outputPanel>  
       <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
       <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
           carsTable.filter(); }" style="width:150px" />  
    </p:outputPanel>  
</f:facet>
```

Comment: i dont need it for global filter. is there anyway to use it for the others?

Comment: INMO , no , at leaset not without modifying the soureces

Comment: @Daniel That would have been my suggestion too.

Comment: @Daniel I am using PF 4.0. I have used the above code snippet but the filter return an empty string. Also I am using the filterEvent as "enter". Am I missing something?

Comment: @VinayChaitankar, make sure you are using the `id="globalFilter"` for your input, if you are and it still does not work post a new question with more info

Comment: @Daniel I have asked the question in another post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071343/primefaces-datatable-filtering-on-enter-key-not-working

Answer (score 1):

It's important to emphasize that filterEvent is an attribute of dataTable tag, in this e.g. [javascript workaround](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/how-to-filter-pdatatable-on-enter-event.html) has showed in the column tag, but this is not work well.
You can use like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="companyTable" 
     value="#{fooManager.foo}" var="foo"
     filterEvent="enter">

    <p:column filterBy="#{foo.name}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{foo.name}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Or you may use with filterEvent="Keyup" which is the default value of this attribute and filterDelay defined in 1000 milliseconds before sending an ajax filter query (Default is 300 miliseconds), like the e.g below:

```
<p:dataTable id="companyTable" 
     value="#{fooManager.foo}" var="foo"
     filterEvent="keyup"
     filterDelay="1000">

    <p:column filterBy="#{foo.name}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{foo.name}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use appropriate option of column now. The simplest example of data column is:

```
p:column filterEvent="enter"
```