# Primefaces datatable filtering on enter key not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I added a global filter to the primefaces datatable. When I hit enter, the filter text is not being sent to the server for query. My code is as follows :

```
<h:form id="searchResultsForm">
<p:dataTable value="#{searchController.resultItems}"
         var="item" editable="false"
         id="searchResultsTable" lazy="true"
         tableStyleClass="viewedHistoryTable"
         emptyMessage="No items"
         widgetVar="searchResultsTableVar"
         currentPageReportTemplate="({startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords})"
         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport}"
         paginator="true" rows="25" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,100"   
         rowKey="#{item.abbr}">
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="Search:" />
        <p:inputText  id="globalFilter" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 13){PF('searchResultsTableVar').filter();}" style="width:150px" placeholder="Filter results"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</f:facet>
<p:column rendered="true">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.title}" />
    <br />
    <h:outputText value="#{item.abbr}" styleClass="searchResultsAbbr" />
</p:column>                                    
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

If I remove the if condition to check the event keycode of Enter, the filter string is sent to the server on every key press. Not sure why the client is sending a empty string on enter. Any ideas?

Comment: try to replace `PF('searchResultsTableVar').filter();` with `searchResultsTableVar.filter();`

Comment: @Daniel I see the same behavior. Filter is empty.

Comment: did you wrapped the table with `h:form` ?

Comment: Yes the datatable is in a immediate h:form. I have edited the question with the h:form.

Comment: dunno, try replace `    <p:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="Search:" />
        <p:inputText  id="globalFilter" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 13){PF('searchResultsTableVar').filter();}" style="width:150px" placeholder="Filter results"/>
    </p:outputPanel>` with `      <h:panelGroup>
       <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="searchResultsTableVar.filter()" />
      </h:panelGroup>` and tell me if that works

Comment: I have tried the above, I think something else is wrong. The inputText loses focus on enter. Not sure if that matters. I will keep trying.

Comment: @Daneil I was able to get it working by just adding a commandButton right after the inputText. Do you think we need both or is it just with my code. Wanted to know your view. I appreciate your help.

Comment: what does that new button do? and are you sure you don't have nested forms ? (form inside a form)

Comment: The button updates the datatable. I have no nested forms. I have a page with 3 layoutUnits. One layoutUnit has a nested form but not the one which has the datatable.

Comment: in general you must always avoid nested form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share my working code :

```
<h:form id="searchResultsForm">                            
<p:dataTable value="#{searchController.resultItems}"
             var="item" editable="false"
             id="searchResultsTable" lazy="true"
             tableStyleClass="viewedHistoryTable"
             emptyMessage="No items"
             widgetVar="searchResultsTableVar"
             currentPageReportTemplate="({startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords})"
             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport}"
             paginator="true" rows="25" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,100"   
             rowKey="#{item.abbr}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{searchController.currItem}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:outputPanel style="padding-bottom: 4px;">                                        
                <p:inputText  id="globalFilter" onchange="PF('searchResultsTableVar').filter();" style="width:60%;" placeholder="Filter results"/>
                <p:commandButton id="Search" value="Search"  process="@this" update="@this" style="font-size: 0.8em;"/>                                        
            </p:outputPanel>                
        </h:panelGroup>                                                                        
    </f:facet>                                                              
    <p:column rendered="true">
        ......
    </p:column>                                    
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a jquery attachment so remove the 'onkeyup' altogether.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#globalFilter').keypress(function(event) {

        if ((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13) {
           PF('searchResultsTableVar').filter();
        }
    });
});
```

Tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zcfga/3/

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem is on "Enter" the string being queried is a empty string. This is happening with PrimeFaces 4.0, I dont think this happens in PrimeFaces 3.4